# html5 canvas creating random rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas

1. why it is producing a type error
2. it took 30 mins to post this question I don't know how much detail it needs to pst this question since I don't know what is wrong with my code I need help
   the code starts from here:-

   ```js
   var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   function rectangle(x, y, dx, dy) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.dx = dx;
     this.dy = dy;
     this.draw = function() {
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.rect(this.dx, this.dy, this.x, this.y);
       ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
       ctx.fill();
       ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
       ctx.stroke();
     }

     this.dipendu = function() {
       if (this.dx + this.x > innerWidth || this.dx - this.x < 0) {
         this.dx = -this.dx;
       }
       if (this.dy + this.y > innerHeight || this.dy - this.y < 0) {
         this.dy = -this.dy;
       }
       this.x += this.dx;
       this.y += this.dy;

       this.draw();
     }
   }
   var rcontainer = [];
   for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
     var x = Math.random() * innerWidth;
     var y = Math.random() * innerHeight;
     var dx = Math.random() * innerWidth;
     var dy = Math.random() * innerHeight;
     rcontainer.push(new rectangle(x, y, dx, dy));
   }

   function animation() {
     requestAnimationFrame(animation);
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

     for (var j = 0; j <= rcontainer.length; j++) {
       rcontainer.update();
     }
   }

   animation();
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>motion</title>
     <style>
       #mycanvas {
         border: 1px solid black;
       }
     </style>
   </head>

   <body>
     <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
     <script src="motion.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Comment: It's exactly what the error message says: `rcontainer` is an array. Arrays do not have an `update` function.

Comment: All you need to change is `rcontainer.update()` to `rcontainer[j].update()`